# How to copy files from a remote computer?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have set up a new pc, and I want to copy data from my old pc to it, without having to manually copy everything to an external drive.

I guess I could do something with rsync over ssh, but have no idea of how to accomplish that.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rsync` is pretty easy to use. You will need to know the ip address or name of the machine. So if your new machine is called `shiny` and the old machine is called `abandoned`, and you have the same user on both machine then to copy to the data over you would type this on `shiny`:

```
rsync avz username@abandoned:/home/user /home/user
```

Substitute the IP addresses if you don't know the names. You should be able to `ping` the other machine if they are on the same network. You can get the IP address by typing `ifconfig`.

Alternatively, you could take the old hdd and mount it either on the machine physically if its a desktop in the spare slot and just copy the files over. Or use a sata/usb lead to mount it, or one of these [toasters](http://www.reghardware.com/2009/01/09/voyager_q/):

Comment: Thanks! I cannot vote up your answer, as I need reputation. When I get it, I'll vote your answer up ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use Nautilus to copy your data from a remote PC: Connect both units via ethernetfor example, open Nautilus on the new machine, press F3 to have two file browsers in your window, navigate the left one to your destination directory and the right one to your source directory (using "network", you need to know username and password of the old machine). Now you can simply drag and drop items from left to right and vice versa.

Comment: How? Can you please add an explanation to the answer?

Comment: I editet my answer.